# Product QTY Increment Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, product, quantity, qty-increment

I've here a problem I try to solve since hours, but don't see the solution.

The packing unit of a product is 100. 
The price for these 100 pieces is e.g. 50 $.

So I set the qty. increment to 100. That works fine and I get the message :

"Product is available for purchase in increments of 100"

But if I try to purchase one item (hundred pieces) the system will not allow that. I've to buy 100. But of course then the unit price will be multiplied with
100.

How to tell the system that 1 unit contains 100 pieces and the price therefor is
50$ and not 100 x 50 $?

Answer (score 5):

Peter, you're trying to use wrong functionality. Quantity increments are meant to be used in cases where you absolutely have to sell something that can't be sold separately, such as six beers in a special package, as doing otherwise decreases its value. This means that you can only choose following quantities: 6, 12, 18, 24 and so on. What YOU want to do is to use bundles: create a new Bundle Product, add associated products as REQUIRED check-box (quantity 100). This way you can choose put one bundle to shopping cart while decreasing stock status of original product by 100 (or in my case by 6). If you need more information search the internet for how to create bundled products, there're TONS of excellent tutorials for scores of languages.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I guess a bundle product is to set up a "build your own product". And you're right. My product can't be sold separately. You can only buy 100, 200, 300 pieces and so on. One unit contains 100 pieces and is it not possible to buy 90 or 120 pieces. And the only thing I want to achieve is, that the system recognize that the order amount of 1 contains 100. And the given price should be the unit price and not the single price. And this seems to be impossible.

Comment: Anything is possible with customization or extensions!

Comment: Besides, all this is achievable using bundles.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the product setup with a price for 100 pieces and set the qty increment to 100 this will happen.

Basically you are saying that each item you sell is worth $0.50 each and you want to sell them in lots of 100 pieces. So your product price should be $0.50